# The necessary and sufficient conditions for surrounding sets of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a problem that I ran into while exploring the distribution of coprimes of a number $n$.

Consider two sequences of natural numbers $R$ and $S$. We'll say $S \ surrounds \ R$ if $ \ \forall r \in R \ \ \exists k$ such that $r-k \in S \land r+k \in S$. That is two say, for each member of $R$, there are two members of S (not necessarily unique) that are equidistant.

What I am trying to find are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $S$ to $surround$ $R$.

$Complete \ sequences$, a related concept, have such conditions, which are quite elegant. I wonder if the conditions for $surrounding \ sequences$ might be equally beautiful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_sequence.

Is there any work that might be useful in investigating this problem?

To simplify the problem, $R$ and $S$ can be taken to be finite, and the members of $R$ can be taken to be contiguous, $\ i.e. R = \{n,n+1,n+2,...,n+k-1,n+k\}$.

The concept of one sequence $surrounding$ another is my own terminology. If this concept has been researched and has existing terminology, please let me know.

Any insights or leads into this subject would be appreciated.